# CMake unable to find Vulkan headers on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python, cmake, pip, vulkan

I am currently trying to install the `kp` or Kompute package for python that makes use of Vulkan.
My problem is that pip is unable to install the package because while its building it returns the following cmake error.

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
        Could NOT find Vulkan (missing: Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

Luckily I have used the Vulkan SDK before and got the same error.
The fix for this was passing `-DVulkan_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/vulkan` to cmake while configuring the project.
I tried this again on a quick sample cmake project, got the same error on `find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)`, passed the same parameter again and afterwards cmake did seem able to find the rest of the libraries itself.

Now my question is if there is any way to tell pip to pass this parameter to cmake? Or even better some way to fix cmake so that it can find the vulkan headers by itself?

Comment: This is either a bug in a package, or a misconfiguration on your part or kompute's part.  The Vulkan SDK does not need you to specific the include directory, for example years ago on Ubuntu with the KDE plasma DE, I did not need to manually specify the vulkan headers, those come from the FindVulkan.cmake itself. I also do not need to currently do this on windows.

Comment: As it stands, this question does not contain enough information for us to figure out why your configuration is failing, we need to see your cmake file at a minimum, and likely need to see much more.  I suggest running a MVCE with out kompute, just the SDK, CMake, and and include to "vulkan.h" using c++.  You do not need much at all to accomplish this even if you aren't familiar with C++ (you won't need to actually use vulkan what so ever).  If that works, then your SDK is fine, and either you didn't follow the directions to install, or Kompute is screwed up, and you need to submit an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by installing the Vulkan SDK from LunarG using the instructions from here: https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/sdk/1.3.239.0/linux/getting_started_ubuntu.html

For my initial install I used the instructions from https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Development_environment#page_Vulkan-Packages which seems like it should have worked properly but for some reason didn't on my system